# Remove multiple Spaces - Unix Script

Tags: unix, sed, tr

From my shell script i am trying to remove repeating white spaces but it seems

```
tr -s " " < input.txt > output.txt
```

is not working. Is there any other way to remove multiple consecutive blank spaces to a single blank space from shell script.

I am trying to remove blank spaces from content

```
1     | First         | PO BOX 123        | DAYTON          | OH            | 3432-222
2     | Second        | PO BOX 2223       | CALIFORNIA      | CA            | 23423 
3     | THIRD         | PO BOX 21         | COLUMBUS        | OH            | 2223
```

into this

```
1|First|PO BOX 123|DAYTON|OH|3432-222
2|Second|PO BOX 2223|CALIFORNIA|CA|23423
3|THIRD|PO BOX 21|COLUMBUS|OH|2223
```

Comment: Are you sure the input has spaces?  `tr` should have worked.  Try  `tr -d '[:blank:]'`

Comment: Looking again, it looks like what you really want is simply `tr -d \\t`, to delete tabs

Comment: tr -d '[:blank:]' worked but it is removing spaces (single space) in the Address as well

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using awk for things that have records. `tr` *tr*anslates text, `sed` is a *s*tream *ed*itor, but `awk` understands the concept of records, fields, field separators, etc.

So to complete your set of options, here's a solution in minimal awk:

```
$ awk -F ' *\\| *' '{$1=$1} 1' OFS='|' input.txt
1|First|PO BOX 123|DAYTON|OH|3432-222
2|Second|PO BOX 2223|CALIFORNIA|CA|23423
3|THIRD|PO BOX 21|COLUMBUS|OH|2223
```

This sets an input field separator with `-F` and an output field separator with `OFS`. The script consists of a statement which causes the record to be rewritten with `OFS`, and a statement (the `1` shortcut) to print the line.

Note the weird escaping of the vertical bar in the `-F` option. If you were to use this, to avoid confusion, you might want to `awk -F ' *[|] *' ...` instead.

To be even shorter at the expense of clarity, you might also use:

```
$ awk -F ' *[|] *' '$1=$1' OFS='|' input.txt
```

This turns the record rewrite statement into a condition which should always return true, thus eliminating the need for the `1` shortcut. While it shaves a few characters off the script, I include it only for fun; much better to use code that doesn't make you scratch your head when you re-read it in a year or two. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Using minimal `sed`:

```
sed 's/ *| */|/g' input.txt
```

Output:

```
1|First|PO BOX 123|DAYTON|OH|3432-222
2|Second|PO BOX 2223|CALIFORNIA|CA|23423 
3|THIRD|PO BOX 21|COLUMBUS|OH|2223
```

Note: This is functionally the same code as *[PaulProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54658327/6136214)*'s answer, but simplified due to the fact that *input.txt*'s whitespace is purely space "" chars, (no tabs, *et al*).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `sed` instead of `tr`:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}|[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/|/g' < input > output
```

or, in perl instead:

```
perl -ne 's#\s+\|\s+#|#g; print;' input > output
```

Comment: Try using the -r flag, some Linux systems require it for extended regular expressions: Like sed -r 's/\s*\|\s*/|/g' < input.txt >  output.txt

Comment: `\s` is a GNU sed extension to regular expressions. Also, `+` is part of extended regular expressions (`sed -E`/`sed -r`), or supported as an extension to BRE in GNU sed, but has to be escaped. So: GNU sed, BRE: `sed 's/\s\+|\s\+/|/g'`, or GNU sed, ERE: `sed -E 's/\s+\|\s+/|/g'` (now `|` has to be escaped!), or POSIX: `sed 's/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}|[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/|/g'`

Comment: tried all the suggestions provided but nothing seems to work. Unfortunately, cannot use perl and have to be in the shell script.  does the os version matters ? I am using Oracle Enterprise Linux 2.6.39

Comment: I believe my issue was different than what the command was supposed to be. It looks like the text file was created in windows and later moved to unix and so is the reason any of the sed and tr commands were not working.   File was regenerated in unix and used the commands provided seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something like this in the /etc/servicesfile.

None of the sed methods worked for me (on this question and many others).

tr -s " " also did nothing
tr -s "\t" removed some of the white spaces (pipelining this to tr -s " " did nothing either)

A solution I found was using 'column -t'

```
 column -t /etc/services | tr -s " "
```

As I understand it (may be wrong) the column command creates a table.
the -t defines the amount of columns (which I think is not specified since it comes from the input file). then I can remove all the extra spaces with 'tr -s " "'.